# JSON Invalid value around character 0 debugging

Tags: json, swift

how do I properly debug the error message

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

I see this in different scenarios happening and I always struggle to find the real reason.
In the case above I have the following url I return a JSON response from:

```
http://SERVERIP/v1/aeds&latitude=48.1848308444472&longitude=11.2527083605633
```

**Server Response via Postman**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "deviceReference": "D200",
      "owner": "Owner 200",
      "latitude": "48.185240",
      "longitude": "11.258890",
      "street": "StreetName",
      "featureTypeId": "1"
    },
    {
      "deviceReference": "D300",
      "owner": "Owner 300",
      "latitude": "48.179290",
      "longitude": "11.253350",
      "street": "StreetName",
      "featureTypeId": "1"
    },
    {
      "deviceReference": "D100",
      "owner": "Owner 100",
      "latitude": "48.176226",
      "longitude": "11.238890",
      "street": "StreetName",
      "featureTypeId": "1"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "Heading 1": "H1",
    "Heading 2": "H2"
  }
}
```

The json gets returned properly in my opinion, still I receive the message, when calling the URL via Alamofire and processing it.

```
func getAEDInRange(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, completionHandler: (Result<[AED], NSError>) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(Router.GetAEDInRange("?latitude=\(latitude)&longitude=\(longitude)")).responseArray { (response: Response<[AED], NSError>) -> Void in
        print(response.result)
    }
}
```

**responseArray Method**

```
public func responseArray<T: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: Response<[T], NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
    let serializer = ResponseSerializer<[T], NSError> { request, response, data, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            return .Failure(error!)
        }

        guard let responseData = data else {
            let failureReason = "Array could not be serialized because input data was nil."
            let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
            return .Failure(error)
        }

        let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
        let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, responseData, error)

        switch result {

        case .Success(let value):
            let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(value)

            // Get Data content of JSON
            let jsonData = json["data"]

            var objects: [T] = []
            for (_, item) in jsonData {
                if let object = T(json: item) {
                    objects.append(object)
                }
            }
            return .Success(objects)

        case .Failure(let error):
            return .Failure(error)
        }
    }
    return response(responseSerializer: serializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

The literal URL in the browser returns:

```
{"data":[{"deviceReference":"D200","owner":"Owner 200","latitude":"48.185240","longitude":"11.258890","street":"StreetName","featureTypeId":"1"},{"deviceReference":"D300","owner":"Owner 300","latitude":"48.179290","longitude":"11.253350","street":"StreetName","featureTypeId":"1"},{"deviceReference":"D100","owner":"Owner 100","latitude":"48.176226","longitude":"11.238890","street":"StreetName","featureTypeId":"1"}],"meta":{"Heading 1":"H1","Heading 2":"H2"}}
```

Comment: According JSON specification the first character must be a `[` or `{`. Paste the literal URL in a browser and check the result.

Comment: This has all the hallmarks of an encoding issue, specifically it sounds like your JSON response is being returned with a BOM that isn't being interpreted/consumed by whatever you're using to read it, so the BOM (likely the characters 0xFE and 0xFF, in that order or the opposite) is retained in the string -- making the string invalid JSON. More in the [Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) and [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: @vadian: That's no longer true, hasn't been for a few years now. (Now a JSON document is allowed to be any valid JSON value, even just `0` or `"foo"`.) And the OP's quoted JSON does (in theory) start with `{`.

Comment: I added the output of the literal url in the browser. But I do not see where this is not valid JSON?

Comment: I found out, when I remove the parameters, that the request works fine. It seems like the paramters cause trouble but how do I find out where. it must be in the parser function.

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON document looks fine, but can't get parsed ("error around character 0"), there are two obvious possibilities for the reason: One, that the JSON document that looks fine isn't the one that you are trying to parse. Two, that it looks fine but isn't fine. For example, if there are zero bytes in the data that translate to invisible characters.

When the error occors, log the first bytes of the NSData as bytes and check what's really there. And log the parsed data converted to a string *at the exact time when the error happens*.

Passing AllowFragments as a parameter is nonsense. You are not expecting a fragment. You wouldn't know how to handle a fragment. If there is a fragment, that's an error to you. So why allow it? At best it causes confusion (because the parsed response now can be a dictionary or array as usually, but also a number, string, or null).

BOMs (byte order markers) are actually allowed at the start of a document, just not inside it - that's something to look for if you have an error in the middle of a document. "Error at byte 0" is quite often a zero byte.